# Simulate expiration of sync token when calling Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

From the documentation (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync):

> Sometimes sync tokens are invalidated by the server, for various
>   reasons including token expiration or changes in related ACLs. In such
>   cases, the server will respond to an incremental request with a
>   response code 410. This should trigger a full wipe of the client’s
>   store and a new full sync.

I need to simulate the 410 error. Is there a way to set the sync token expiration date? I tried changing the access control data of the calendar but the sync token is not invalidated.

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary? If you want to do this for testing purposes, you don't need to invalidate the actual sync token. The server will return a 410 when you try to incremental sync, so you can just mock that part and make sure your program handles a 410 return correctly (do full sync instead).

Comment: In my situation I cannot create mocks. I just have a link to a web page that creates these requests to Google Calendar API and I wonder if there is a way to test how it behaves in this case. As a side note, I managed to get 410 error by calling the API using updatedMin parameter with a value that is "too far in the past" according to the response. The url looks like this: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR_ID}/events?updatedMin=2014-12-01T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 9):

I recently needed to test the 410 response scenario in my code. In my case it turned out to be really simple to trigger the 410 response.

I store the sync token in the database, which looks something like "CIiV7urvy84CEIiV7urvy84CGAU=".

I was able to change the sync token to trigger the 410 response. I changed to "1CIiV7urvy84CEIiV7urvy84CGAU=", adding a "1" at the beginning.